# Run all cells above in a Spark notebook in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

What keyboard shortcut can be used to run all cells above in a Spark notebook in Azure Synapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a keyboard shortcut to run all cells above but you can access this from the Run menu, ie

[image: Run cells above]

It might be worth keeping an eye on the shortcuts page in case it ever gets added:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks?tabs=preview#shortcut-keys